# ssh: keep persistent terminal session with spotty connection

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal

I have a spotty vpn connection and I need to run commands that take a long time (usually around half an hour), and require input at different times through the process.  Is there some way to start a terminal session that can be suspended, or moved to the background, when my VPN cuts out, but then brought back to the foreground in a new SSH session when it comes back up?

Comment: Have you tried Mosh yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

screen  and tmux are both designed to do exact this.

Comment: I have no experience with tmux. how do I bring up a lost connection?

Comment: @ewok You reconnect over SSH (or whatever other method you use to connect) and then run either `screen -R` (if you're using screen) or `tmux attach` (if you're using tmux).

Comment: Never used it - I use screen myself very occasionally. I think it's "screen -r" - but really this is quite trivial and you need to learn to use Google and man pages.